# Outcome of array is null?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I posted a question not long ago, which was answered and helped me a lot. Sorry to post again so soon. =/

I have gone over this, and not sure what I have done wrong, the printed outcome is several 'null' words. I am trying to populate a 2d array with data from a text file by using a method. Then run that method in the main class to print out the populated array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance. =)

Main Class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ScoreProcessor scores = new ScoreProcessor();

    String[][] table = scores.readFile();


    for (int row = 0; row < table.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < table[row].length; col++) {
            System.out.print(table[row][col] + "\t");
        }
    }
}
```

Another Class, that includes the method:

```
    public class ScoreProcessor {

    static public String[][] readFile() throws IOException {

        File filedata = new File("src/JavaApp2/Data.txt");
        Scanner file = new Scanner(filedata);

        int row = 0, col = 0;

        String[][] scores = new String[8][5];


        while (file.hasNext()) {

            Scanner readfile = new Scanner(filedata);
            readfile.nextLine();
            readfile.useDelimiter(",");

            while (readfile.hasNext(",")) {
              String line =  readfile.next();


             line = scores[row][col] ;
                col++;
            } // end innerloop
            row++;
            col = 0;


        } // end outerloop

        return scores;
    } // end method
} // end class
```

Data File

```
Student,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4
abcd0001,50,55,59,72
efgh0002,82,78,84,86
ijkl0003,42,45,46,52
mnop0004,66,74,72,78
qrst0005,82,86,89,88
uvwx0006,77,83,87,82
yzab0007,62,64,70,68
```

Comment: how does your Data.txt file look like?

Comment: Your inner loop will not read the entry *after* the last comma, I think. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Please show us the output, too. Is every element `null` or just one field?

Comment: Why do you open 2 scanners???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out, file.hasNextInt() returns false, as the you're reading lines not int. Since it's null your code never gets into the loop and the data is not feeded.

```
   Scanner readfile = new Scanner(filedata);
   String line1 = readfile.nextLine();
   readfile = readfile.useDelimiter(",");
```

Don't open the file again, just read each line and split it by ','

```
String line = file.nextLine();

for (String each: line.split(",")) {
   scores[row][col] = each;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. It seems to be working as intended now. :)

Answer (score 2):

The line

`while (file.hasNextInt())`

will return `false`.  Hence your array will not be initialised with data and return `null` prints.

I would advice to put your check on the fact if  `readfile.nextLine()` returns `null` or not.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 public class ScoreProcessor {

        public static String[][] readFile() throws IOException {

            File filedata = new File("src/JavaApp2/Data.txt");
            Scanner file = new Scanner(filedata);

            int row = 0;

            String[][] scores = new String[8][5];

            while(file.hasNextLine()){
                String line=file.nextLine();
                scores[row]=line.split(",");
                row++;
            }

            return scores;
        } 

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            String[][] table = readFile();

            for (int row = 0; row < table.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < table[row].length; col++) {
                    System.out.print(table[row][col] + "\t");
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the definition of [hasNextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29).  It will return false if the next token is not intepretable as an int.

The way I see it, your file starts with "Student", or if you skip the header row, with "abcd0001", but not an int.  So `hasNextInt()` will return false right away, and your inner loop is never exeucted.

Beyond that, it's not clear to me why you instantiate a second `Scanner`.

An issue like this can be very easily traced with a debugger, I suggest you familiarize yourself with that approach :)

Answer (score 0):

use file.hasNext() insted of file.hasNextInt() and it should resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Isn't also this (besides HasNextInt()) the core of the problem:

```
line = scores[row][col] ;
```

should be other way around. This way your array will never be filled and of course always contain only nulls.

```
scores[row][col] = line;
```